# Firebase DB Query in my saved keywordlist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image][image]

In my android app, I am storing product list in this structure. But I need to check that keyword contains my searched text. I am using this query

```
Query query= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(productList)
  .orderByChild("keywords").startAt("bag").endAt("bag\uf8ff");
```

But it is not working,Please help me in this part.Otherwise say a correct structure to save keywords in my app FirebaseDB.

Comment: Firebase cannot efficiently query for the existence of a child in a collection/array. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value. If you have problems making that work, share the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will include a snippet of your actual JSON, which you can get by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Hi Frank,I added my JSON snipp too..please help me

Comment: Thank you Frank,With your guidance and poisonmind help,its working.I achieved what i am expected...Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks @poisondminds for helping in my absence!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database doesn't work so well with "contains" like matching like you want. Rather, a better suggested way to structure this would be to give each "product" a list  of keywords instead of storing it in a comma separated string.

```
"productList":
{
    "id1":
    {
        "keywords":
        {
            "bag": true,
            "bang": true
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

This sort of structure is explained further in the [Firebase Realtime Database Structure Guidelines](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data). It then makes it much better for querying. You could then do the following to find products with that keyword...

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(productList).orderByChild("keywords/bag").startAt("");
```

Comment: i tried with this DB structure,stored keywords in HashMap(String,Boolean).But this query returned null only.

Comment: @MariP did you rename your `keyword` node to `keywords`? Can you update the question with an export of your firebase database so I can see the exact structure ?

Comment: @poisondmind..yes i rename my node keywords and saved the list of string in Hashmap.but still that query return null only.

Comment: @MariP I just looked at your json. If you look at the link in my answer, it shows that you shouldn't use `false` for values within a list like structure. Instead, just don't include it. The reason the query is not coming up with anything is because you don't have any items with `bag: true` in the keyword list